# Creating advanced search query with PHP Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I've started developing a project and I need use a advanced search query with *PHP* and *Mysqli*, but I'm getting some troubles. Check out below my query.

```
$query = "SELECT id, name, keybox, posterid, alias, xmdb from `datasys` WHERE name LIKE '%".$filter."%' OR keybox LIKE '%".$filter."%' ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 10";
```

It's working perfeclty! But still not matching entries that contains symbols, for example, if my database contains a row called **"Color: red"** and someone type **"Color red"**, the query will return empty, but if I type "Color: red" returns found. So, what should I do to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: You can use REGEXP instead of LIKE in WHERE clause to be more specific

Comment: I guess you need FULLTEXT index for your kind of search, [take a look here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html). This is working for InnoDB  or MyISAM tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use the REGEXP as:-

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnName REGEXP "regular_expression";
```

or use REPLACE() function in WHERE clause as:-

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE REPLACE(columnName, ":", "") LIKE "like_expression";
```

Comment: Using replace, it's possible add hyphen too? Like REPLACE(columnName, {":", "-"}, "") ?

Comment: yes, you can chain REPLACE() function as `replace(replace(columnName,'oldCharOne','newCharOne'),'oldCharTwo','newCharTwo')` and so on.

Comment: I'm applying it in a new query but gives me error, saying that I've a wrong syntax: **$query = "SELECT id, nome, keybox, posterid, alias, xmdb from `movies` WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(nome, ':', ''), '-', '') LIKE '%".$filter."%' OR WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(keybox, ':', ''), '-', '') LIKE '%".$filter."%' UNION SELECT id, nome, keybox, posterid, alias, '0' from `series` WHERE WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(nome, ':', ''), '-', '')  LIKE '%".$filter."%' OR WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(keybox, ':', ''), '-', '') LIKE '%".$filter."%' ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 40";**  . How can I fix it?

Comment: Also, sorry for the wrong formatting, I'm facing some problems with this recently

Comment: you have used WHERE twice in the query as `from series WHERE WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(nome, ':', ''), '-', '')`, However, as far as the use of REPLACE() is concerned, you are using it in a proper way. Can you paste the error logs or message which you get while executing the query as well?

Comment: I've removed the repeated WHERE and the problem persists. Here is the error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(keybox, ':', ''), '-', '') LIKE '%casa%' UNION SELECT id, ' at line 1

Comment: I don't know what I did but I fixed the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that I can think of in order to maintain consistency is that you can eliminate the ':' in your query for matching. Try the below query:

```
$query = "SELECT id, name, keybox, posterid, alias, xmdb from `datasys` WHERE REPLACE(name, ':', '') LIKE '%REPLACE(".$filter.", ':', '')%' OR REPLACE(keybox, ':', '') LIKE '%REPLACE(".$filter.", ':', '')%' ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 10";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But it's not only ":", I just used it as example. It's possible use for ":" and "-" too?

Answer (score 0):

Use two queries to find exact and similar records.
If the records available in Exact data query then no need to run the similar data query

```
 <?php
//Fetches Exact Data
    $query = "SELECT id, name, keybox, posterid, alias, xmdb from `datasys` WHERE name LIKE '%".$filter."%' OR keybox LIKE '%".$filter."%' ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 10";

    //If the previous query doesn't return any value, then use
    //Split the the user input and then query DB
    $condition="name!=''";
    $filters=explode(" ",$filter);
    foreach($filters as $val)
    {
        $condition.=" or (name LIKE '%$val%' OR keybox LIKE '%$val%')";
    }
//Fetches Similar Data
    $query = "SELECT id, name, keybox, posterid, alias, xmdb from `datasys` WHERE $condition ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 10";

    //-----------ENDS
    ?>
```